# Web address (URL) lookup by company name

Tags: url, search

I need a web service that will return url(s) of sites owned by a particular company.  So when I type in "microsoft" in the text input field it would return a list of results like http://www.microsoft.com.  Any advice on how to do this?  I was thinking Google's Custom Search API.

Comment: Just use Google's API and search for the company's name. The first hit  should be the right one if the company invested a dollar into internet marketing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a url lookup to see if websites exist, and then have the code try different website names and/or extensions (.com, .org, .net, https://, etc.)

for example; if you put in

```
    Logitech
```

it could give you:

```
    http://www.Logitech.com
    http://www.Logitech.net
    http://www.LogitechCompany.com
    http://www.LogitechCompany.net
```

But only if those sites actually exist.